# How to reproduce Excel's TDIST function using Math.NET

Tags: c#, excel, statistics, distribution, mathnet-numerics

I am attempting to reproduce the same results of Excel's `TDIST()` function in Math.NET.

In my tests, Excel produces the following value for this two-tailed Student's T-Test:

**Excel**

```
1 - TDIST(0.84, 8009, 2)
result: 0.599066539
```

In Math.NET, however, I am unsure how to calculate the same result. Math.NET's documentation does state that it uses a simplified version of Student's T (namely, one that accepts location and scale parameters). In my limited understanding, location can either be the mean, median, or mode. I am not sure what scale refers to other than a larger scale means that the distribution will be more spread out. I am looking for insight into these two parameters as I believe they are where I am veering off course.

**Math.NET**

```
double result = 2 * (1 - StudentT.CDF(0, 1, 8009, 0.84))
result: 0.40093346073350911
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very close. My Math.NET example was equivalent to `(1 - TDIST(0.84, 8009, 2))`, so I merely needed to subtract that from 1:

```
double result = 1 - (2 * (1 - StudentT.CDF(0, 1, 8009, 0.84)))
```